# Determining the symmetry operations of an arbitrary molecule

Tags: symmetry, molecules

I need to write a code that's determining the symmetry of a molecule, knowing the coordinates of the atoms. Many quantum chemistry codes do that already, but I don't know exactly how.

Suppose I want to know if an axis $C_n$ is a symmetry of the system, what is a simple way to determine that, not knowing exactly a priori the direction of the axis? The same question applies to symmetry planes $\sigma$.

We do know that the center of mass of the molecule is unaffected by point group operations. So, I thought, I'd make grid of points and for each point, I'd consider a line passing through it and the center of mass of the molecule. Then I could rotate the system around those lines, establishing which one of them is closest to rotation axis. I could do the same for improper rotation, and then also consider planes parallel or perpendicular to the axes to check for reflections.

Somehow, I believe I'm missing something and this method, though it might work, is not what people are typically doing.